# contact form providing error

Tags: php, html, email

I have two contact forms on my website: www.davek.us and I can not get them to send emails. Both pop up with no results and are stuck on "please wait". Any help would be appreciated.

Contact Forms:

```
          <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content flat-tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab0">
              <form action="sending_mail.php" method="post" id="contactForm" name="contactForm">
                <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Message Contact Form">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Your Name (*)</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control form-flat" name="fullname" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Email (*)</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control form-flat" name="email" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Phone (*)</label>
                  <input type="phone" class="form-control form-flat" name="phone" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Your Message (*)</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control form-flat" name="message" rows="8" required></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <div id="captcha1"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-flat-solid primary-btn" >Send Message</button>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="preload-submit hidden"><hr/> <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Please Wait ...</div>
                  <div class="message-submit error hidden"></div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab1">
              <form action="sending_mail.php" method="post" id="hireForm" name="hireForm">
                <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Message Hire Form">
                <input type="hidden" name="file" id="file-att" value="">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Your Name (*)</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control form-flat" name="fullname" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Email (*)</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control form-flat" name="email" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Phone (*)</label>
                  <input type="phone" class="form-control form-flat" name="phone" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Short Description About of Project (*)</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control form-flat" name="message" rows="8" required></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Attach Your Document <span class="display-block color-dark"></span></label>
                  <div class="clearfix">                        
                    <input type="button" id="upload-btn" class="btn btn-flat-solid btn-file btn-xs btn-default  clearfix" value="Choose file">
                    <div id="errormsg" class="clearfix error"></div>                  
                    <div id="pic-progress-wrap" class="progress-wrap"></div>    
                    <div id="picbox" class="attbox color-dark"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div id="captcha2"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-flat-solid primary-btn">Send Request</button>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="preload-submit hidden"><hr/> <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Please Wait ...</div>
                  <div class="message-submit error hidden"></div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div><!--End Tabs-->
```

PHP sending_mail.php  : https://pastebin.com/9nFbfszN

PHP Errors: `

> [20-Jul-2017 20:10:22 UTC] PHP Warning:  mail(): Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header in /home/davidkryszczak/public_html/php/sending_mail.php on line 60
>   [20-Jul-2017 20:12:05 UTC] PHP Warning:  mail(): Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header in /home/davidkryszczak/public_html/php/sending_mail.php on line 60
>   `

Comment: So, you managed to paste html, but failed to paste php-code?

Comment: check for the *real* error